# Remote Desktop services local login and remote sessions?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rds

If i have a server with Remote Desktop Services installed, could I log in locally (keyboard/mouse/monitor attached) and login remotely and still share all sessions? Will Windows allow this? Will it just share the allowed sessions (per my CAL) without kicking people off?

I am wondering if I could place this server under a desk so one of my users could use it in the office, if not possible then I will have to put the server in the closet somewhere and give them a means of RDP'ing into the server.

Answer (score 0):

to start i'd say RDS is not my area, I'm more of a team viewer person. 
However, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754397.aspx
Microsoft has detailed instructions on line regarding connections and monitoring connections. You can share the session without kicking them off, yes. (Similar to Team Viewer, you can both be looking at the same screen and doing things but from two locations. you just both can't perform two different actions.)
Regarding placement, Depending on your server, a closet might be best anyway providied it has ventilation, space, etc. Otherwise, yeah, go for it, my server is sitting right next to me in a closet, it really depends on security and size/vent needs.
Hope This helped!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I have 5 CAL license and 4 remote users as of now. I am wondering if someone were to login locally, would that just use up another one of my CALs?

Comment: @KPS Only RDS connections require RDS CALS.